# SQL Reporting Services 2016 - "Content Manager" predefined role not listed

Tags: sql, ssrs

When assigning system roles to users, I *only* see "System Administrator" and "System User". I need to add a user with "Content Manager" as a role but do not see this option. SQL Reporting Services 2016 on Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the http://reportservername/Reports/browse page, click on "Manage Folder"  then from http://reportservername/Reports/manage/catalogitem/security/ page you can click add group or user.  You should then see full list.